# Joint mass function conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

> Let $(X,Y)$ have joint mass function
>
> $$p(k, n) = \frac{C \cdot 2^{-k}}{n}, \quad \text{for } k = 1, 2, \ldots \text{ and } n = 1, \ldots, k$$
>
> and suitable constant $C$. Keeping in mind $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. Find $E[X \mid Y=y]$

My attempt was to use the conditional probability definition; find $P_Y(y)$ then we have $p_{XY}(x,y)$ already so we just combine them.

However, while I was computing my $P_Y(y)$ I faced an issue: I get

$$P_Y(y)=\frac{C}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{-k}\,,$$

but when I did calculation because my $k$ is not starting from $0$ I was not sure if I could use regular series formula to get     $\frac{2C}{n}$, and I got stuck. My goal was to use that to compute

$$p_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y) = \frac{p_{XY}(x,y)}{p_Y(y)}$$

then use it for $E[X \mid Y=y]$.

Do you think my $P_Y(y)$ calculation wrong, or the way I am going is wrong overall?

Comment: If you draw a picture of all $(k,n)$ values on the support of your joint PMF it will have a triangle shape,  and requires $k\geq n$, so for each positive integer $n$ we get $$P_{Y}(n)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}p_{X,Y}(k,n)=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} p_{X,Y}(k,n)=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{c}{n}2^{-k}$$ Note that $2^{-k} = 2^{-n}2^{-(k-n)}$.

Comment: I have find the whole thing after your comment as  $\frac{2C}{y} \cdot 2^{-y}$ Py I mean